# Populate associated entities on DBContext Find

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Product which needs to have some fields in multiple languages. Therefore I have made a ProductLanguage table which has the composite key and language specific fields (ProductID, LanguageID, Name).

In my Product class I tried something like this:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();

    public Product()
    {
        this.Multimedias = new List<Multimedia>();
        this.ProductLanguages = new List<ProductLanguages>();
        this.ProductLanguage = db.ProductLanguages.Find(this.ID, Global.Language) ?? new ProductLanguage();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Multimedia> Multimedias { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductLanguage> ProductLanguages { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ProductLanguage ProductLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

So I could immediately access the language specific fields without needing to go through the collection - the problem is the object obviously doesn't have the ID yet.

Is there any way so when I do

```
Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
```

in the controller it will automatically populate my ProductLanguage property?

Comment: How do you set ProductLanguages? If it's in the collection already, why do you have a separate property for one? Mixing model and DB access can get messy.

Comment: It is in the collection already, I would like a separate property so I don't duplicate "product.ProductLanguages.Where(x => x.LanguageID == y)" all over my code and perhaps forget it somewhere and lose language specific text.

Comment: But why do you use db.ProductLanguages? Couldn't you use the ProductLanguages collection?

Comment: Yes I suppose so, but that still doesn't help me as the ProductLanguages collection at this point in the code is also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your assignment of ProductLanguage in the Get for that property.

Comment: So used to seeing empty gets and sets I didn't even contemplate that haha, thank you.

Comment: Be advised that by setting `ProductLanguage` with the getter, you'll be issuing a silent query to actually get those related languages in the `ProductLanguages` collection. Instead of using `Find(id)`, you should use `Include("ProductLanguages").SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id)`. Then, everything will be queried at once.

Comment: Yes, or add an is null check in the Get.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the property

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual ProductLanguage ProductLanguage { get; set; }
```

The `ProductLanguages` collection will be populated via lazy loading when you hit it. What you need is a method like this, that will return a ProductLanguage by id:

```
public ProductLanguage GetProductLanguageById(int id)
{
    if (ProductLanguages != null)
    {
        return ProductLanguages.Where(pl => pl.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not confirming to any practice/usage i have seen before.., regardless I would consider it **very!! very!!** bad practice. Don't make an instance of your context within the Entity(table).

Also why are you doing this... I suggest you read up on Lazy and eager loading.

Quote
*"in the controller it will automatically populate my ProductLanguage property?"*

Yes.... use eager loading.

```
Product product = db.Products.Include("ProductLanguage").Find(id);
```

But I would highly suggest that you don't do all that other weird stuff in the initialization of your entity.

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
Product product = db.Products.Include("ProductLanguage").Find(id);
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't even notice that bit in the OP's code. Yes, definitely, you should never interact with your context inside an entity, and definitely, you should never create an instance of your context within an entity. @Seabizkit: You can't use `Include` and `Find` together. If you want to use `Include`, you have to use something like `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: If you look at comments under question, you'll see he doesn't need to use db.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger yeah sozs your probably right but you knew what i meant. ;-)